# test for popup with QUnit

Tags: qunit, pnotify

I'm trying to see whether a popup is shown after a certain action. The popup is done with [pnotify](http://sciactive.github.io/pnotify/) and puts a `div.ui-pnotify` in the DOM. I can see the notification popping up in the tests, but I can't seem to test it's visibility with QUnit, most probably because of a delay. Anybody here with experience in this area?

```
ok(find('div.ui-pnotify').length, 'Name has been changed');
```

Chrome console:

```
<div class="ui-pnotify " style="width: 300px; right: 25px; top: 25px; opacity: 1; display: block; cursor: auto;"><div class="alert ui-pnotify-container alert-success ui-pnotify-shadow" style="min-height: 16px;"><div class="ui-pnotify-icon"><span class="fa fa-check"></span></div><div class="ui-pnotify-closer" style="cursor: pointer; visibility: hidden;"><span class="fa fa-times"></span></div><div class="ui-pnotify-sticker" style="cursor: pointer; visibility: hidden;"><span class="fa fa-play"></span></div><h4 class="ui-pnotify-title">Persoonlijke gegevens</h4><div class="ui-pnotify-text">Uw persoonlijke gegevens zijn opgeslagen.</div></div></div>
```

Comment: Could the person that downvoted my question explain me why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not familiar with `find()`, unless you're using [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.find), which won't work for various reasons.  However, this test works for me:

```
QUnit.test('example', function () {
    ok($('div.ui-pnotify').length, 'Name has been changed');
});
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5XS4e/)

Comment: thanks for going through the extra trouble of creating the jsFiddle.